# Postgresql service not starting in services. windows2012

Tags: postgresql

PostgreSQL service not starting in `services.msc`. It is showing below message while starting PostgreSQL service in Window server 2008 R2.

> The PostgreSQL-x64-11-PostgreSQL server11 service on local computer started and then stopped some services stop automatically if they are not in use by other services or programs.

Answer (score 0):

I had checked the error in event viewer 
postgres: could not access directory "D:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/11/data": Unknown error

postmaster.pid file was missed.Due to reason service not started. 
Solution: I created blank file postmaster.pid on same location after that restarting the service resolves the issue.